# Saving an excel sheet as a PDF while refreshing the information every time

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete novice in VBA and I need to create a Macro that generates and saves PDFs from an excel sheet.

I have an output sheet that pulls out information from other sheets depending on the number that is entered in my D2 cell. (every number is related to a set of information and there are around 500 sets, so I need 500 PDFs).

I would need to build a macro that repeats these steps every time:

- Enter a number from the list in my D2 cell (so that information refreshes)
- Saves the output sheet as a PDF naming the file with the number in my D2 cell
- Repeats the process for every number on the list

I have seen some code to build a Macro to save sheets as PDF but I am struggling with the code to iterate the process hundreds of times.

Has anyone worked on anything similar or has any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can record macros while performing actions in EXCEL.

Answer (score 0):

This is already a beginning:

```
Dim pdf_number As Range

For Each pdf_number In Sheets("your_sheet").Range("range_with_your_pdf_numbers")

    'change value in D2 based on your number
    Sheets("output").Range("D2") = pdf_number.Value 

    'This should refresh your output sheet
    Application.Calculate
    
    '... Your code to save you pdf ...

Next
```

Basically, this will go through a range of numbers (... that you should define somewhere, in another sheet for instance - I miss information to know where/if you have these numbers), and update the cell D2 for each one of these numbers. You can then do what you want inside this loop, such as save it as pdf. You can also use the "pdf_number.Value" to generate your pdf file name.